# How to compute the distance between 2 ranked lists?

Tags: python, ranking

Let's say I have some ranked lists:

```
A = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat']
B = ['dog', 'cat', 'cow']
```

How do I compute a similarity score between the lists A and B that considers the number of items that overlap between the lists and their relative ordering. Is this something that nDCG is used for?

Comment: None of the items in your lists overlap when you consider ordering. If you are asking about algorithms, probably better to check the mathematics or datascience stack exchange.  Otherwise, it would help to clarify what type of score you want, and what weight the rank should have.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Kendall's Tau](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kendalltau.html).
You need to generate a "rank" vector (each value in the vector is the rank of the corresponding item).

First, from these "ranking" vectors :

```
A = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat', 'mouse']
B = ['dog', 'cat', 'cow']
```

You create the domain (all your items):

```
domain = list(set(A + B))
```

The index of each item in the list is important because it will help to generate "rank" vectors:

```
['cat', 'dog', 'bat', 'mouse', 'cow']
```

Then you generate the rank (same size as domain) of A and B with missing items as ties (last rank)

```
A_rank = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B_rank = [2, 1, 4, 4, 3]
```

You can write a function for that.

And finally you use the Kendall's Tau to get a score between -1 and 1:

```
from scipy import stats
correlation = stats.kendalltau(A_rank, B_rank)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual request. Typically lists are compared based on the number of shared elements regardless of their position or based of the absolute order of elements in the list.
Relative positioning ("bar" after "foo" regardless of their absolute position in the list)  is much rarer and difficult case.

Sometimes this is done in the field of NLP, which might be of use to you, since your example contains a list of strings.

1. Identify phrases in your corpus (all lists you want to compare). This can be done using gensim.phrases model ( https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html ) ;
2. Convert lists of strings into BOW vectors ( example here: https://maelfabien.github.io/machinelearning/NLP_2/#2-bow-in-sk-learn );
3. Compute similarity between vectors using cosine similarity .

The end metric will take into account both the overall similarity between lists and the relative order of elements in them.

This could depend on the specific use-case. If you are working with text data and you seek to identify instances when one word is used after another word (i.e. a Phrase) and then compare two documents in terms of overall similarity of vocabulary used and the precise phrasing,